# Why is my 3D text gameobject in Unity becoming clear instead of changing color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, colors

I am trying to get my 3d text gameobject in Unity to change to a random color when the ChangeColor() function is called but it is instead becoming clear. I used the same code on a cube and it worked but it is not working with this text. Thank you for any help!
Here is my code:

```
public class ColorChanger1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color[] shapeColor = new Color[5];
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = shapeColor[1]; //this was an attempt to just set it to one of the colors in my color array but it also turned the text clear
        ChangeColor(); 

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void ChangeColor()    {
        var textRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (shapeColor.Length > 0)
        {
            int newColor = Random.Range(0, shapeColor.Length);
            textRenderer.material.color = shapeColor[newColor];
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you using TextMesh? TextMesh has its own Color property that is separate from the renderer.

Comment: yes I am using text mesh @ErikOverflow

Comment: Does `new Color[n]` automatically populate the array? It looks like you just create an array but don't put any Colors in it.

Comment: You may need to modify the TextMesh component instead of renderer. var textRenderer = GetComponent<TextMesh>(); and then textRenderer.color = shapeColor[newColor];

Comment: I add the colors in the inspector @ToivoSäwén

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a TextMesh's color, you need to modify the TextMesh component's color, not the generic Renderer's material color.

```
var textMesh = GetComponent<TextMesh>();
if (shapeColor.Length > 0)
{
    int newColor = Random.Range(0, shapeColor.Length);
    textMesh.color = shapeColor[newColor];
}
```

Comment: If I do that it registers in the text mesh section of the inspector that it is changing color however in the actual scene and game view it is still showing as clear upon play. @Erik Overflow

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your inspector window for this GameObject? @philipdority

Comment: I'm sorry how do I share a picture on here? @Erik Overflow

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VvuZ36HO2zuDvg17Ai1WsIEdvxWNKNuq/view?usp=sharing     here is a google file link to the screenshot, apparently I need more rep points to just share a screenshot @Erik Overflow

Comment: In my assets it may look like those colors are the ones I used but I simply created the RGB colors by hand in the Shape Color Element boxes, idk if that is important or not. @Erik Overflow

Comment: The alpha value on your colors is 0, @philipdority

Comment: you saint thank you! I did not realize that fourth bar was affecting the color @Erik Overflow